# Apply function to vectorised column values in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Please consider this

```
library(data.table)
mydt <- 
  data.table(id = 1:100,
           p1 = sample(seq(0,1,length.out=1000),100))
mydt$p2 <- 1 - mydt$p1
```

I want to apply a function using as the argument a vector from columns `p1` and `p2`.

```
myFun <- function(x) {
  sample(c(1,2), 1, prob = x)
}
```

This works,

```
mydt$outcome <- apply(mydt[,2:3], 1, myFun)
```

but I have a 25M rows, so I reach the memory limit.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
mydt[,mydt := mapply(myFun, p1, p2)]
```

Comment: If you want to benefit from `data.table`, I recommend to stick with `data.table` syntax. So, to create a new column `p2` in `mydt` use `mydt[, p2 :=  1-p1]` instead of `mydt$p2 <- 1 - mydt$p1`. It will update `mydt` _by reference_, i.e., without copying the whole object.

Answer (score 2):

`prob` argument in `sample` requires a vector. And to apply `myFun` to each row, you can use `by=1:nrow(mydt)` or `by=1:mydt[,.N]`

```
mydt[, chosen := myFun(c(p1, p2)), by=1:nrow(mydt)]
```

---

Hat-tip to @Roland for his usage of `rbinom`. His vectorized version for this Bernoulli trial is much faster.

```
> system.time(mydt[, chosen := myFun(c(p1, p2)), by=1:nrow(mydt)])
   user  system elapsed 
   4.82    0.00    4.86 
> system.time(mydt[, outcome2 := rbinom(.N, 1, p2) + 1])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.05    0.02    0.06
```

data used in timings:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
m <- 1e6
mydt <- data.table(id = 1:m, p1 = runif(m))[, p2 := 1 - p1]
myFun <- function(x) sample(c(1,2), 1, prob = x)
```

accuracy check:

```
n <- 0L
while (n < 1e3) {
    set.seed(n)
    mydt[, chosen := myFun(c(p1, p2)), by=1:nrow(mydt)]

    set.seed(n)
    mydt[, outcome2 := rbinom(.N, 1, p2) + 1]

    if(!all.equal(mydt$chosen, mydt$outcome2)) stop("mismatch")
    n <- n + 1
}
```

Comment: This is still a slow loop. I think, `mydt[, outcome2 := rbinom(.N, 1, p2) + 1]` should do the same, but can't fully reproduce the result even when setting the seed.

Comment: thanks, @Roland. Your vectorized method will be certainly be faster. I don't think the results will ever match even with seeding.

Comment: Why not? I would have expected them to match. E.g., `set.seed(42); 
x <- replicate(100, sample(0:1, 1)); 
set.seed(42); 
y <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5); 
all.equal(x, y)`